# Best place to validate constructor input

Tags: java, exception, constructor

I'm not sure what the best practice for the location of validating input for my constructor would be, I could put logic outside of the constructor or accept the input and do logic to check inside the constructor

For my current validation I read a line from a csv, split the fields on the comma and check that there is the right number of fields and the right size, then pass them to the constructor. Would it be better to do these kind of validation inside the constructor and throw an exception?

The code that calls the constructor:

```
while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = fileIn.nextLine();
    String[] fields = line.toUpperCase().split(",");
        if(!fields[0].isEmpty()) {
            objects.add(new Object(fields));
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid field from file");
        }
}
```

The Object constructor currently:

```
    public Object(String[] objectFields ) {
        super();
        this.objectNameType = objecctFields[0];
        this.objectNum = objectFields[1];
        }
```

What I want to do, but unsure if this is a good practice:

```
    public Object(String[] fields ) {
        super();
            if(!fields[0].isEmpty()){
                this.objectNameType = fields[0];
                this.objectNum = fields[1];
            }else{
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are the risks in doing it each way? @SeanBright Are there downsides to static factory method? I actually never used that setup for constructors because it wasn't how I learned, usually I would validate file data as soon as it reads out, before it goes to any methods.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you did it the way you want to, you'd presumably still be calling the

```
objects.add(new Object(fields));
```

but if the field[0] is empty, you would be adding a null object to your objects data structure. Personally, I would do it the way you currently have it set up, that way you don't run the risk of having null objects added to "objects"

Answer (score 0):

It is generally better for any method or constructor to validate their parameter values as soon as possible. You can document such restrictions and fail quickly giving the right exception.

If an invalid parameter is passed and you fail to check its validity, many things can go wrong. The other methods of that class may fail with some confusing exception or worse it could give some wrong result which can be harder to debug.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it doesn't matter, I think, but it's not a good practice to do the validations inside the constructor. 
Suppose your class Object is a subclass of several classes and they have many fields that are initialized at the time of declaration. In that case, all your super-class hierarchy and their fields will be initialized before your validation. Now after all these initialization processes (which may be time-consuming), you throw an exception because of a field being null - which doesn't make sense.
So, I recommend doing the validations before calling a constructor or via a static factory method.